# Check status if Raspberry Pi is connected to any WiFi network (Not Internet necessarily) using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, wifi, raspbian

I don't want to check if it has Internet connectivity! I just want to check if it's connected to the WiFi network (I'd have already given its SSID in the WPA_supplicant file).. This network won't have Internet access.

Comment: Do you want to check it from the inside of the py or from the outside?

Comment: Using the Pi, I'll be running the Python script in the Raspberry Pi only.

Comment: You could consider  pinging a few big websites, and consider the internet down if all are down

Comment: @DanIonescu  I don't want to check if it has Internet connectivity! I just want to check if it's connected to the WiFi network (I'd have already given its SSID in the WPA_supplicant file).. This network won't have Internet access. Do you get it?

Answer (score 6):

#### Problem

`iwconfig` didn't work for me, but `iwgetid` did.

How do I solve this issue?

#### Code

```
import subprocess
ps = subprocess.Popen(['iwgetid'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(('grep', 'ESSID'), stdin=ps.stdout)
    print(output)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    # grep did not match any lines
    print("No wireless networks connected")
```

Comment: Careful with this solution. If your wifi adapter is attempting to connect to a network (even if it will be rejected due to something like an incorrect password), this command will still show the SSID as connected during the attempts.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are running some kind of linux (like raspbian), you don't need to use Python for this, the easiest way would be:

```
iwconfig 2>&1 | grep ESSID
```

from the command line or a shell script. There will be output if you are connected to a wireless network, and no output if not. You could wrap this in `subprocess` if you want to run it from Python:

```
import subprocess
ps = subprocess.Popen(['iwconfig'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(('grep', 'ESSID'), stdin=ps.stdout)
    print(output)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    # grep did not match any lines
    print("No wireless networks connected")
```

Comment: Works fine! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

you caN use the following lines of code to check the IP address assigned to the RPI

```
t="$(ifconfig wlan0 | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}')"
echo $t
w=${#t}
echo $w
```

use any condition check after this 
such as to check the width.

Answer (score 0):

t="$(ifconfig wlan0 | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}')"
echo $t
w=${#t}
echo $w

i run this code output comes 0.

if i am running simple is command

t="$(ifconfig wlan0 | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}')" echo $t w=${#t} echo $w

output comes like w=0 echo